# Rust compiler does not unify types that both `impl Future<Output=()>` in branches of `if let` expression

Tags: rust, rust-async-std

While trying to create a Future conditionally, for later use with `select_biased!`:

```
            let mut heartbeat_timer = if let ServerState::Leader(_, _, _) = server_state {
                // if we're the Leader, we want to send out AppendEntries RPC at a
                // minimum interval as required to maintain our leadership
                task::sleep(HEARTBEAT_DURATION)
            } else {
                // if we're not the leader, no need to send those
                pending::<()>()
            };

// ...

            select_biased! {
                h = heartbeat_timer => self.heartbeat().await,
                // ... some others declared in priority order
                default => task::yield_now().await,
            }
```

I am having difficulty understanding why I get a compilation error:

```
error[E0308]: `if` and `else` have incompatible types
   --> src/raft.rs:185:17
    |
182 |               let heartbeat_timer = if let ServerState::Leader(_, _, _) = server_state {
    |  ___________________________________-
183 | |                 task::sleep(HEARTBEAT_DURATION)
    | |                 ------------------------------- expected because of this
184 | |             } else {
185 | |                 pending::<()>()
    | |                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected future, found `Pending<()>`
186 | |             };
    | |_____________- `if` and `else` have incompatible types
    |
    = note: expected opaque type `impl futures::Future<Output = ()>`
                    found struct `futures::future::Pending<()>`
```

Clicking (in my IDE) through `pending` shows me that its type is `Pending<T>`, and I can further see that `Pending<T>` implements `Future<Output=T>`:

```
impl<T> Future for Pending<T> {
    type Output = T;

    fn poll(self: Pin<&mut Self>, _: &mut Context<'_>) -> Poll<T> {
        Poll::Pending
    }
}
```

For some reason I can't yet understand, the compiler fails to follow the same breadcrumbs. What secret does the compiler know that am I missing? Is there some straightforward transformation of my code that would satisfy the compiler? What should I be thinking that would have led me to supply what the compiler needs?

`rustup --version` includes the output:

```
info: The currently active `rustc` version is `rustc 1.69.0 (84c898d65 2023-04-16)`
```

Comment: Types in Rust don't "unify" around traits. A variable in Rust can only have one type, and the two arms of the conditional indeed do not return the exact same type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`impl` return types don't work that way, unfortunately. They aren't dynamic dispatch; an `impl` return type must still be a *single* concrete type; it's just that you don't have to specify the type in your code. If you have two (or more) branch arms that return different types, then the `impl` return will reject it. If you want to do that, you have to use full dynamic dispatch. That means a `dyn` trait object and a `Box` or other indirection mechanism.

In your case, I might recommend replacing `impl Future<Output=()>` with `Box<dyn Future<Output=()>>`. On each of the branches, you'll have to do an explicit `Box::new` around the desired return value to add the layer of indirection.

Comment: To list another option, [`either::Either`](https://docs.rs/either/latest/either/enum.Either.html) is a way to effectively do dynamic dispatch without a heap allocation.